# Jenkins needs to know where your Maven is installed

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins runs into error while locating "maven" folder, for Maven type project:

> Jenkins needs to know where your Maven is installed. Please do so from the system configuration.

Just about the place where `pom.xml` location is to be mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

As stated in the above answer, you need to set-up maven in Global Tool Configuration. Name your Maven & check the install automatically option. Jenkins will automatically install Maven before building the project[image]

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [Bug JENKINS-34743](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34743), you need to set Maven Location in `Global Tool Configuration = Jenkins initial page > Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration`